# scroll between Nav and components Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have created a vue single page this way:

My app.vue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <Navegacion/>
    <Cabecera/>
    <Contenido/>
    <Aside/>
    <Footer/>
   
  </div>
</template>
```

My navigation.vue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>

    <div class="flex flex-row blanco">
        <div class="item-uno">
            <nav class="flex flex-row items-center">

                <a @click="desplazar" href="#">Quienes somos</a>
                <a @click="desplazar" href="#">Cómo funciona</a>
                <a @click="desplazar" href="#">Servicios a empresas</a>
                <a @click="desplazar" href="#">Compromiso</a>

            </nav>

        </div>

        <div class="item-dos flex justify-center">

            <img id="logo" src="../assets/logo.svg" alt="logo apeteat">

        </div>

        <div class="item-uno flex justify-center items-center">

            <a class="btn blue">Nuevo pedido</a>
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
               <i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i>
               <p>0,00 €</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    
</template>
  <script>
  export default {
name: 'Navegacion',
props: {
},
methods: {

  desplazar: function() {
   window.scrollTo(0,200);
    }
  }
}

  </script>
```

I want to make scroll to the correspondent component when clicking on a navigation link.

I have installed npm scroll-to, and I have tried to add a function methd desplazar but it's not working.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143590/9524228 you can check this response

Answer (score 0):

`window.scrollTo()` is javascript window method, you don't need to install anything to use it.

It works in your code but `href="#"` always throw you at the top of the page so it's cancelling window.scrollTo().
You need to remove `href="#"` from your links.

To scroll to component first you need to add ref to it like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <Navegacion ref="Navegacion" />
    <Cabecera ref="Cabecera" />
    <Contenido ref="Contenido" />
    <Aside ref="Aside" />
    <Footer ref="Footer" />
   
  </div>
</template>
```

and your function should looks like this

```js
scrollToNavegacion() {
   window.scrollTo(0, this.$refs.Navegacion.$el.offsetTop);
}
```