# In Vue.js, how do I scroll to an imported component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, components

I know about the scrollBehavior function that Vue has, but I am unsure of how to use it with my code.

I have an Index page, where sections are made of imported vue components.
For example

```
<template>
  <div class="Container">
   <About />
   <Services />
   <Contact />
  </div>
</template>
```

My Navbar has links to all these components.

```
    <template>
    <nav>
    <img class="nav__logo" :src="navLogo" height="40px" width="auto">
        <ul class="nav__row" ref="nav">
            <div class="nav__row__dropdown-toggle-btn" @click="toggleNav">
                <img :src="navMenuIcon" height="40px" width="auto">
            </div>
            <li class="nav__list-item" v-for="(link, index) in navLinks" :key="index"
                @mouseover="hover = true"
                @mouseleave="hover = false"
                :class=" { active: hover } ">
                <router-link :to="link.path">
                    {{ link.text }}
                </router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
```

which it gets from my App.vue script

```
    <script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer'
export default {
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Footer
  },
  data: () => ({
    navLinks: [
      {
        text: 'Home',
        path: '/'
      },
      {
        text: 'About',
        path: '/about'
      },
      {
        text: 'Contact',
        path: '/contact'
      },
      {
        text: 'Services',
        path: '/services'
      }
    ]
  })
}
</script>
```

but if I click on "About" it will just take me to a seperate page for the "About" component.
When I click on "About" I want the page to scroll down to the imported About component that is nested on my Index page.

How can I accomplish this? Is it something I need to change in the path?

Comment: That's not how Router works. Typically, somewhere in the template of your App.vue there's a `<router-view />` tag. Upon navigation to different routes, that tag gets replaced by the component the route points to. What you seem to want is an application where all the components are present in the same page and a scrollspy function which changes the route dynamically based on scroll position (without changing the contents of the page). Probably the simplest way of achieving it is taking an already existing scrollspy navigation demo and replacing its sections with your "pages".

Answer (score 0):

The idea of router that you trying to implement is actually treating About components as a page, and when clicking at it, it will go to that page (and change URL)

So, in order to implement what you want, I actually suggest using pure javascript

First, give the `About` component and id ( or ref if you prefer Vue ref)

```
 <template>
      <div class="Container">
       <About id="about"/>
       <Services />
       <Contact />
      </div>
    </template>
```

Then bind a method to click event of nav

```
 <li class="nav__list-item" v-for="(link, index) in navLinks" :key="index"
                @mouseover="hover = true"
                @mouseleave="hover = false"
                :class=" { active: hover } ">
                @click=nav(link)
            </li>


data: () => ({
    navLinks: [
      {
        text: 'About',
        id: 'about'
      }
    ]
  }),

methods:{
  nav(link) {
          const position = document.getElementById(link.id).offsetTop;
          // smooth scroll
          window.scrollTo({ top: position, behavior: "smooth" });  
   }
}
```

If you prefer Vue ref, can change all id to ref. And use `this.$refs[link.id].$el.offsetTop` instead;

Answer (score 0):

i found this video so useful,
my goal was able to scroll between component at the same page.
but still you can apply anywhere, i think

https://laracasts.com/series/practical-vue-components/episodes/1